# Presto - How can i compare two arrays to get the maximum matched values count

Tags: arrays, presto

I want to compare the user array with defined array and get the maximum matched values count.

I looked using "transform" in presto, but not able to proceed to the solution

```
Compare ( A[1,2,3,1,4,7,1,2,1,8] , B[1,2,3,4,5] )
```

Here, array A is to be compared with array B.
The values that A has that are in B are 1,2,3,4

So, Expected output: 4

Comment: This question does not seem to any connection with **database** and **mysql**

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_intersect`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#array_intersect) to find the common elements between the two arrays, and then [`array_max`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#array_max) to find the max value in the intersection.  For example:

```sql
WITH t AS (
    SELECT ARRAY [1,2,3,1,4,7,1,2,1,8] AS x, ARRAY [1,2,3,4,5] AS y
) 
SELECT array_max(array_intersect(x, y))
FROM t;
```

will results in `4`.

All of the array functions are documented here: https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html